# Code:ServiceError, Error : connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1

Tags: botframework

Recently i have updated my Bot emulator from v4.0 alpha to v4, after that its always giving ECONNREFUSED error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That error only appears if Emulator is unable to connect to your bot. Here's what you can do to troubleshoot:

1. Verify that your bot is running
2. Verify that your bot is using the correct port. Your image shows that Emulator is listening on `:62738`, but the `.bot` file normally defaults the development endpoint to `http://localhost:3978`

It kind of looks like you created a `.bot` file that contains endpoints for your own bot plus a few samples. Although this could probably work, it's probably best to keep one `.bot` file per bot.

Comment: Thanks, Problem is with my windows os, its not listening to 127.0.0.1. After executing this command "netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1", its working properly.

Comment: @AnjireddyVangala Interesting. I've never seen that before and we all use Windows OS on the bot team. Does it make a difference if you use `localhost` vs. `127.0.0.1` in your `.bot` file? How were you starting the bot (command prompt, vs code terminal, visual studio, etc)? Is there anything special about your machine that might cause this? I'm hoping to get more info to help other users troubleshoot this better in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I am running from visual studio, In recent windows update i got this problem.

Comment: @AnjireddyVangala Good to know. Thanks for the info!